# Multiple user processes accessing kernel linked list

Tags: linux, multithreading, linked-list, linux-kernel, system-calls

I have 10 user space application which could invoke the same system call to kernel. For example 10 user space program could invoke bind system call.

Upon receiving the system call, my code in the kernel would insert a data in linked list I created in the kernel space. I am using kernel linked list to add, remove and traverse node. I am also locking the node before writing to prevent the scenario where the list is not corrupted when accessed simultaneously by different user space processes.

I am concerned that when any of these 10 processes invokes system call to the kernel space, the corresponding the kernel thread of a user process doesn't know how to access the custom list head and update the list.

The reasoning behind this concerns is that the system call are not atmoic, i.e 10 user application can be started at a same time but there is no guarantee that the one that was started first is going to run and complete first. How does the corresponding kernel thread know which kernel list to update which can also be updated by 9 other kernel thread.

In nutshell, Is my concern valid? if yes, how do I make sure that the same kernel linked list can be accessed by the kernel threads without any issues of concurrency and race condition issues? Do I need to create a shared linked list inside kernel so that the kernel thread/user process that it needs to get access to the specific list and update that only? 
If my concern is valid please provide me information how to implemented shared kernel linked list?

Comment: `how do I make sure that the same kernel linked list can be accessed by the kernel threads without any issues of concurrency and race condition issues?` - Perform accesses to the list with a lock taken. I am failed to understand what do you want. What is "shared linked list" and so on. Can you provide some code for explain your problem?

Comment: How does different kernel thread can get access to the head of the kernel linked list ?

Comment: Let me correct above, How do different KERNEL PROCESSES can access to the head of the kernel linked list ? (Since, kernel can have multiple threads for a single user space process, so I refer KERNEL process to make sure those are instances of different user space process)

Comment: Assuming you have a **global** list **variable**, any kernel thread can access the list using name of that variable. What is a problem with that approach?

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev. I learned that kernel being Monolithic code, it is one single process which can have multiple threads and those threads can access the global list variable without need of any special IPC mechanism. All those thread need is handling of concurrency/race condition issue which is explained in chapter 5 of LDD3.