# kernel linked list in shared memory

Tags: linked-list, linux-kernel, shared-memory

I want to create a kernel linked list inside a shared memory. I have implemented kernel linked list based on the https://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/

Now, I want to put the list into shared memory created inside kernel so that different user application case access the list and update/remove node. 
Different user application makes system calls to add/remove/update the kernel linked list.

Do I need to use mmap or something else to achieve the same? Any example?

Comment: If by "shared memory" you mean memory area **directly** accessible by kernel and user (that is, user doesn't need to use system calls for read/write bytes from that area), then yes, you may implement (in kernel) device file, which can be mmap()-ed by the user. But if the only way for user to operate with that memory is a **syscall** (ioctl, read/write file, etc.), then this is just a kernel memory, which could be allocated by `kmalloc` or other means from the kernel. Which case is yours?

Comment: I am on the second case, where user will operate on the kernel linked list using system calls only, But those system call could come from different user space applications as well as different threads of a user application. What shall be the implementation of kernel linked list? what are the things I will have to take care of?

Comment: As I [commented your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818610/multiple-user-processes-accessing-kernel-linked-list#comment82599986_47818610), you just need to use some *locking mechanism* (spinlocks, mutexes, etc.) around the linked list's accesses. If you don't familiar with spinlocks or mutexes I suggest you to read some book about Linux kernel programming.

Comment: I don't think I am conveying my question properly.

Comment: I believe that for each user space application there is a corresponding kernel process. Also the fact that two kernel process can not access the data structures of each other until they have some IPC mechanism in place. The data structure in this case is the linked list and both kernel processes needs to share that for which I am looking for a solution. I thought mmap can solve that issue, if you disagree with what I believe please provide insight into why and how two different kernel processes can access a single list list without IPC mechanism.

Comment: `the fact that two kernel process can not access the data structures of each other` - This is not true for Linux kernel. In Linux, all kernel processes **share kernel data**. Anything allocated within one kernel process is visible by other kernel processes. [But kernel processes don't share access to *user-space* memory.]

Comment: Any proof to backup your statement? In Linux, all kernel processes share kernel data. Anything allocated within one kernel process is visible by other kernel processes. If that is the case why we have IPC in kernel space at all?

Comment: Please, read some book about Linux kernel programming. E.g. [Linux Device Drivers, 3d-edition](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/).

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev. I learned that kernel being Monolithic code, it is one single process which can have multiple threads and those threads can access the global list variable without need of any special IPC mechanism. All those thread need is handling of concurrency/race condition issue which is explained in chapter 5 of LDD3.